# how to set localization in google recaptcha

Tags: javascript, java, recaptcha

I am using google recaptcha in my web application. My web application works for both English and French. Is it possible to add the localization in my google recaptcha too?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can set language in recaptcha option. Place this code before you call recaptcha.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
var RecaptchaOptions = {
lang : 'fr'
};
</script>
```

The language codes are available [Here](https://developers.google.com/recaptcha/docs/language?hl=en).

If you want to render recaptcha automatically using the widget, [Here](https://developers.google.com/recaptcha/docs/display?hl=en) is the documentation is available.

You can use Javascript resources(api.js) by passing hl parameter to it.

Comment: This doesn't work, passing language as hl parameter works

Answer (score 23):

Even you can set it when you want to initialize

```
<script src='https://www.google.com/recaptcha/api.js?hl=en'></script>
```

Answer (score 4):

Note, it is not lang but hl now

```
var RecaptchaOptions = 
{
    'sitekey' : '6LcgSAMTAAAAACc2C7rc6HB9ZmEX4SyB0bbAJvTG',
    hl : 'fr'
};

grecaptcha.render('html_element', RecaptchaOptions );
```